# Laravel Eloquent: multiple nested relationships with 3 level deep

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, relationship

I have 3 level deep tables:

```
1.plan -> 2.steps -> 3.nomenclature
```

and i need no load object nomenclature with 2 different nested tables

```
3.1 - uom (1:1)
3.2. - ingredients (1 to many)
```

i use **hasManyThrough** now to receive nomenclature object. And i can add 3.1 uom to this object:

```
$plan = Plan::with(['steps', 'items.nomenclature.uom'])
```

**but how can i add *3.1 uom* and *3.2. ingredients* at same time to the nomenclature object?**

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In the model of items we need add to relation

```
with(['nomenclature', 'uom'])
```